# window server 2008 fail to import p12 cert

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a P12 Cert signed by Apple Developer Program,
I place the cert in file system (C:/)

and then i double-click to open it, 
simply type in correct password and click next and next, finally it show a error dialog say :( the file is empty.)

I have take a screen shot below, anybody know what is the problem?
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am having the same issue. Have you found a solution?

Comment: I found the solution, the P12 file should combine the key file.If the P12 file only contain the personal information, it maybe 2-3KB, if include the key, it should be almost 6KB file. The key is generate from my boss, It may be done via the apple developer program page.